# Represent node with same parent

Tags: lists, grouped-list, listview

I need to show a list of active items. Every item has more than one parent.
I want to group them by parents with a treeview, but I have this situation:

```
- Parent A
  - Child A
  - Child B
- Parent B
  - Child B
  - Child C
```

How can I group items by parent without have this scenario? 
I think that treeview isn't the best choice for that, but I don't know a better solution.

Comment: What are you trying to achieve? A treeview is a parent child relationship (one to many)

Comment: @DarrylGodden
I want to show a list of items and associate with their parents, also by color or other. 
When user select an item, he can know which parents have that item.

Comment: @Unicorn365 Are you trying to show this on a website, or on a chart/image, what is the goal of displaying these items?

Comment: @DasBeasto Hi, I try to show on a web application

Comment: @Unicorn365 Can users select either Children or Parents? Would they have a reason to look from both perspectives?

Comment: @MikeM User can select only children, but he must know which parents are connected to them

Answer (score 1):

A hierarchy relationship is more related to what you are trying to achieve. Without any further information.

[image: Hierarchy]

Comment: How can I represent this structure? Which is the best component to show something similar?

Comment: Because of its nested nature, HTML does not have a native structure which neatly captures this kind of relationship (elements can only have a single parent). Instead, you'll need to use elements for nodes, and separate elements for connections between them. I have done a similar thing by loading my nodes, specifying the parent(s) and child(ren) nodes in `data` attributes, and then using javascript to draw SVG connections between them. That sort of code is probably out of scope for UX, and better suited to stackoverflow.com